# Drop down mobile menu is not pushing the content

Tags: html, css, sass

I wanted my mobile menu to push down the content below it. Here the content is the footer. What is the thing I am doing wrong here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m9fc6wnq/

Comment: No css in the jsfiddle mb the link to /style/site.css don't work online, try adding you css in the jsfiddle

Comment: hey, it's my bad! Please, check now. http://jsfiddle.net/m9fc6wnq/3/

Comment: what you mean by pushing down? may you show me the result you like to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the rule `grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;` that in max-width: 840px works with this one: `header {display: none; }`.

With these 2 rules, when you are in max-width 840px, your first row become your `.menu` and you put its height on 40px.

This is an exemple of what I say. I created 4 rows putting a `display:none` on first one: you see the second line takes the rule of the first one.

```css
#grid{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: 20px 100px 40px 100px;
}
.a_1{
  background-color:yellow;
  display:none;
}
.a_2{
  background-color:orange;
}
.a_3{
  background-color:blue;
}
.a_4{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="a_1"></div>
  <div class="a_2">I'm the second row but I'm height only 20px</div>
  <div class="a_3"></div>
  <div class="a_4"></div>
</div>
```

So, the solutions could be different: remove `grid-template-rows` rules (removing also grid-row: -1; in your footer) or change that rule when you are in max-width:840px. It depends on your layout and what you need to do.

I'll give you an example changing the rules `grid-template-rows` adding:

```
@media (max-width: 840px) {
  .wrapper{
    grid-template-rows: auto 40px;
  }
}
```

```js
    const triggerButton = document.getElementById('triggerButton');
    triggerButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const x = document.getElementById("menu");
        if (x.className === "menu") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "menu";
        }
    })
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins");
/*Media queries*/
body {
  margin: 0px; }

/* container */
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(autofit, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px; }

/* header */
header {
  grid-column: 1 /-1;
  background-color: #0966A7;
  color: #f8f6f6;
  font: 400 14px 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr auto 1fr; }
  header div.left-header {
    grid-column: 1/2; }
  header div.right-header {
    grid-column: 6/6;
    justify-self: end; }
  header div > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 8px; }
    header div > ul li {
      margin-left: 20px;
      display: inline-block; }
      header div > ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white; }
        header div > ul li a i {
          background-color: #309071;
          border-radius: 50%;
          padding: 5px; }
  @media (max-width: 840px) {
    header {
      display: none; } }

/* Menu */
.menu {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  justify-self: center;
  font: 400 14px 'Poppins', sans-serif; }
  .menu a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #222121;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 16px; }
  .menu a:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 20px; }
  .menu .icon {
    display: none; }
  .menu .menu-brand > img {
    max-width: 120px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle; }
  .menu .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden; }
  .menu .dropdown .dropbtn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin-top: 21px; }
  .menu .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0966A7;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1; }
  .menu .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0; }
  .menu a:not(:first-child):hover {
    background-color: #309071;
    color: black; }
  .menu .dropdown .dropbtn:hover {
    background-color: #309071; }
  .menu .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #309071;
    color: black; }
  .menu .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block; }
  @media (max-width: 840px) {
    .menu {
      justify-self: auto; }
      .menu a:not(:first-child), .menu .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
        margin: 0; }
      .menu a.icon {
        margin: 21px;
        float: right;
        display: block; } }

@media (max-width: 840px) {
  
  .wrapper{
    grid-template-rows: auto 40px;
  }
  .menu.responsive {
    position: relative; }
    .menu.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0; }
    .menu.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
      position: relative; }
    .menu.responsive .dropdown {
      float: none; }
    .menu.responsive .dropdown-content {
      position: relative; }
    .menu.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left; } }

footer {
  grid-row: -1;
  background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
   <div class="left-header">
    <ul>
     <li>Call: 272 727 2727</li>
     <li>info@kolorscopy.com</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="right-header">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Branches</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>

    </ul>
   </div>
  </header>

  <div class="menu" id="menu">
   <a href="/" class="menu-brand"><img src="images/kolors-logo.png" alt=""></a>
   <a href="/">Home</a>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">About
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="/about-kolors">About Kolors</a>
     <a href="/vision-and-mission">Vision & Mission</a>
     <a href="/before-and-after">Before & After</a>
     <a href="/video-gallery">Video Gallery</a>
     <a href="/reviews">Reviews</a>
     <a href="/testimonials">Testimonials</a>
     <a href="/how-it-works">How it works</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Slimming
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="/weight-loss-programs">Weight Loss</a>
     <a href="/inch-loss-treatment">Inch Loss</a>
     <a href="/figure-correction-body-sculpting">Figure Correction</a>
     <a href="/body-alignment-beauty-therapy">Body Therapy</a>
     <a href="/body-toning-treatment">Body Toning</a>
     <a href="/liposculpting-lipo-gel">Lip Gel</a>
     <a href="/cool-sculpting">Cool Sculpting</a>
     <a href="/bmi-calculator">BMI Calculator</a>
     <a href="/how-it-works">How it works</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Skin
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="/skin-care-treatment-clinic">Skin Clinic</a>
     <a href="/skin-fairness-treatment">Fairness Treatment</a>
     <a href="/anti-aging-skin-treatment">Anti Aging Treatment</a>
     <a href="/deep-scar-removal">Deep Scar Removal</a>
     <a href="/laser-treatment-for-hair-removal">Laser Hair Removal Treatment</a>
     <a href="/skin-polishing-treatment">Skin Polishing</a>
     <a href="/mole-and-natural-warts-removal">Mole & Warts Removal</a>
     <a href="/under-eye-dark-circles-treatment">Under Eye Dark Circles</a>
     <a href="/best-wrinkle-treatment">Wrinkle Treatment</a>
     <a href="/best-natural-acne-treatment">Acne Treatment</a>
     <a href="/best-dark-spot-removal-treatment">Dark Spot Treatment</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Hair
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="/hair-transplantation">Hair Transplantation</a>
     <a href="/hair-re-growth">Hair Re-Growth</a>
     <a href="/hair-strengthening-treatment">Hair Strengthening</a>
     <a href="/best-anti-dandruff-treatment">Anti Dandruff</a>
     <a href="/anti-hairfall-treatment">Anti Hairfall Treatment</a>
     <a href="/prp-treatment">PRP Hairloss Treatment</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <a href="#">Academy</a>
   <a href="#">Products</a>
   <a href="#">Franchise</a>
   <a href="#">Contact</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" id="triggerButton">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
   </a>
  </div>



  <!--{{# each navLinks}}
 <li {{#ifeq ../section key}} class="active" {{else}} {{/ifeq}}>
  <a href="{{ href }}">{{ label }}</a>
 </li>
 {{/each}}-->

  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

 </div>
```

...and one removing that rule (removing also grid-row: -1; in your footer as I said before)

```js
  const triggerButton = document.getElementById('triggerButton');
    triggerButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const x = document.getElementById("menu");
        if (x.className === "menu") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "menu";
        }
    })
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins");
/*Media queries*/
body {
  margin: 0px; }

/* container */
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(autofit, 1fr);
   }

/* header */
header {
  grid-column: 1 /-1;
  background-color: #0966A7;
  color: #f8f6f6;
  font: 400 14px 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr auto 1fr; }
  header div.left-header {
    grid-column: 1/2; }
  header div.right-header {
    grid-column: 6/6;
    justify-self: end; }
  header div > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 8px; }
    header div > ul li {
      margin-left: 20px;
      display: inline-block; }
      header div > ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white; }
        header div > ul li a i {
          background-color: #309071;
          border-radius: 50%;
          padding: 5px; }
  @media (max-width: 840px) {
    header {
      display: none; } }

/* Menu */
.menu {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  justify-self: center;
  font: 400 14px 'Poppins', sans-serif; }
  .menu a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #222121;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 14px 16px; }
  .menu a:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 20px; }
  .menu .icon {
    display: none; }
  .menu .menu-brand > img {
    max-width: 120px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle; }
  .menu .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden; }
  .menu .dropdown .dropbtn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin-top: 21px; }
  .menu .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0966A7;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1; }
  .menu .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0; }
  .menu a:not(:first-child):hover {
    background-color: #309071;
    color: black; }
  .menu .dropdown .dropbtn:hover {
    background-color: #309071; }
  .menu .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #309071;
    color: black; }
  .menu .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block; }
  @media (max-width: 840px) {
    .menu {
      justify-self: auto; }
      .menu a:not(:first-child), .menu .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
        margin: 0; }
      .menu a.icon {
        margin: 21px;
        float: right;
        display: block; } }

@media (max-width: 840px) {
  
  .menu.responsive {
    position: relative; }
    .menu.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0; }
    .menu.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
      position: relative; }
    .menu.responsive .dropdown {
      float: none; }
    .menu.responsive .dropdown-content {
      position: relative; }
    .menu.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left; } }

footer {
  background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
  crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
   <div class="left-header">
    <ul>
     <li>Call: 272 727 2727</li>
     <li>info@kolorscopy.com</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="right-header">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Branches</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>

    </ul>
   </div>
  </header>

  <div class="menu" id="menu">
   <a href="/" class="menu-brand"><img src="images/kolors-logo.png" alt=""></a>
   <a href="/">Home</a>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">About
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="/about-kolors">About Kolors</a>
     <a href="/vision-and-mission">Vision & Mission</a>
     <a href="/before-and-after">Before & After</a>
     <a href="/video-gallery">Video Gallery</a>
     <a href="/reviews">Reviews</a>
     <a href="/testimonials">Testimonials</a>
     <a href="/how-it-works">How it works</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Slimming
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="/weight-loss-programs">Weight Loss</a>
     <a href="/inch-loss-treatment">Inch Loss</a>
     <a href="/figure-correction-body-sculpting">Figure Correction</a>
     <a href="/body-alignment-beauty-therapy">Body Therapy</a>
     <a href="/body-toning-treatment">Body Toning</a>
     <a href="/liposculpting-lipo-gel">Lip Gel</a>
     <a href="/cool-sculpting">Cool Sculpting</a>
     <a href="/bmi-calculator">BMI Calculator</a>
     <a href="/how-it-works">How it works</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Skin
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="/skin-care-treatment-clinic">Skin Clinic</a>
     <a href="/skin-fairness-treatment">Fairness Treatment</a>
     <a href="/anti-aging-skin-treatment">Anti Aging Treatment</a>
     <a href="/deep-scar-removal">Deep Scar Removal</a>
     <a href="/laser-treatment-for-hair-removal">Laser Hair Removal Treatment</a>
     <a href="/skin-polishing-treatment">Skin Polishing</a>
     <a href="/mole-and-natural-warts-removal">Mole & Warts Removal</a>
     <a href="/under-eye-dark-circles-treatment">Under Eye Dark Circles</a>
     <a href="/best-wrinkle-treatment">Wrinkle Treatment</a>
     <a href="/best-natural-acne-treatment">Acne Treatment</a>
     <a href="/best-dark-spot-removal-treatment">Dark Spot Treatment</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Hair
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="/hair-transplantation">Hair Transplantation</a>
     <a href="/hair-re-growth">Hair Re-Growth</a>
     <a href="/hair-strengthening-treatment">Hair Strengthening</a>
     <a href="/best-anti-dandruff-treatment">Anti Dandruff</a>
     <a href="/anti-hairfall-treatment">Anti Hairfall Treatment</a>
     <a href="/prp-treatment">PRP Hairloss Treatment</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <a href="#">Academy</a>
   <a href="#">Products</a>
   <a href="#">Franchise</a>
   <a href="#">Contact</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" id="triggerButton">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
   </a>
  </div>



  <!--{{# each navLinks}}
 <li {{#ifeq ../section key}} class="active" {{else}} {{/ifeq}}>
  <a href="{{ href }}">{{ label }}</a>
 </li>
 {{/each}}-->

  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/main.js"></script>


 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, man!  And changing the `grid-template-rows` to `auto 40px` worked out. But, I don't kinda get the logic here. Why would the footer depend on `40px` of the header which you suggested to remove?

Comment: You're welcome! :) The problem was that with `header{display:none}`, your first row become menu. So your menu become 40px height and can not expand. Changing `grid-template-rows` to `auto 40px;` your new first row (menu) coud expand itself: your new layout have only 2 rows, so => `auto 40px`. But, as I said, you could remove that rule, if you want (see the second solution) and you have not the problem to change the number of rows.

Comment: Excellent answer @resedano, and once again thank you for your pretty good explanation!

Comment: It was a pleasure! Happy to have helped you :)